# ASP.NET MVC4 Code First - Data validation doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem with data validation in forms. I declare error messages in model but it seems that it doesn't have any effect in the View. I have the following model:

```
public class Dog
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Minimum value is 1")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in View I have this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
```

The problem is that there is no error message when user chooses to enter number which is lower than 1 as you can see here:

[image]

What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you add modelstate.isvalid in your controller?

Comment: Did you reference the jquery-validation plugin?

Comment: @Jeroen - Yes, it's added but how to display error message?

Comment: refer this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

Comment: @Icarus - Thank you :) I missed it. I put it in _Layout.cshtml and it seems it's working well now.

Comment: @Icarus - please add your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it, and give you credit.

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin I am glad it worked. I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, I am adding this as the answer:

Add a reference to the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation/)

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the no tags, no references or any mentions of jQuery validation, we can safely see you're trying to validate the **good old fashioned way** (the out of the box way).

You have to **invoke** the validation yourself in your post method, by calling `ModelState.IsValid`. If that fails, the error messages will show on the erroneous fields. You'd had something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (Dog model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //He's a good dog, save him, then redirect elsewhere
    }
    else
    {
        //He's a bad dog, return the same view and the errors are shown
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you (good example :) ) but I can't see any errors like that. I solved it with jQuery at the end.